# Replace get/test/set of bare references with Optional.ofNullable(...).ifPresent(...)?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a mutator method that sets only the non-null fields provided in an argument. The argument returns bare references, not `Optional` wrappers, and this cannot be changed.

Before Java 8, one way to do this would have been:

```
Double h = arg.getH();
if ( null != h ) setH( h );

Double v = arg.getV();
if ( null != h ) setV( v );

String s = arg.getS();
if ( null != s ) setS( s );

// Etc. ...
```

Starting with Java 8, it is possible to express this more concisely with a throwaway `Optional`.

```
Optional.ofNullable( arg.getH()).ifPresent( this::setH );
Optional.ofNullable( arg.getV()).ifPresent( this::setV );
Optional.ofNullable( arg.getS()).ifPresent( this::setS );
// Etc. ...
```

This idiom is less familiar. However, it also eliminates a potential source of error -- such as the error in the "before Java 8" code above.

**Question: Is there any negative impact to frequent use of this newer pattern?** (*For example*, how does it compare to the earlier pattern in compiled size or performance?)

Comment: Bench it on your target env, it is the only valid answer

Comment: The second variant creates temporary objects whereas the first does not. They are irrelevant for most real-life cases, but there still are developers feeling bad about such things. Besides that, it’s more a matter of code style. I would rather focus on the question, why there are `Double` objects in the first place…

Comment: If the code is executed frequently enough, it's likely to hit an threshold and gets optimized (i.e. inlined) by the HotSpot compiler. The memory impact shouldn't be that big either, as the optional is just a wrapper and gets cleaned up by the youngGenGC very quickly. So I agree with Nicolas, bench it!

Comment: You're asking whether the performance cost (basically, two object creations) is worth the concision, but I think that's the wrong question.  Just as one can easily over-obsess on performance, one can do the same with concision.  The real goal should be _clarity_.  As @jpkrohling suggests, many users will find the convoluted use of `Optional` to be less readable than the original version.

Comment: Escape analysis should make those two variants equivalent, but that only applies to JITed code and a JVM which actually has that optimization. And if the stars are not correctly aligned it might fail.

Comment: @the8472: it is correct, that not every code undergoes Escape Analysis, but that only implies that the objects may not be entirely elided in all cases, not that the actual creation of a purely local object has an impact on the performance per se.

Comment: @Holger if they're not elided then it at least increases young GC pressure. They're cheap, but not free.

Comment: @the8472: the performance of the young GC depends on the number of *surviving* objects, which doesn’t change when you raise the number of *temporary* objects. Given the ratio of the size of these temporary objects and that of the TLAB, you only cause the young GC to happen 0.0…% earlier.

Comment: @Holger earlier means more frequently. which decreases throughput and may also affect GC heuristics. with enough temporary objects this is noticeable. Death by a thousand cuts. As i said, they're cheap but not free.

Comment: @BrianGoetz - Reduced clarity would certainly qualify as one of the negative impacts that this question asks about. I understand that concision taken to an extreme can reduce readability. (I've read some bad Perl.) That said, this is a re-occurring pattern. As with streams, it would help to have a standard mechanism to express the *intent*, rather than repeated long, possibly flawed expressions of mechanics. I personally find the idiom above more readable, but hear you that some may not. Any suggestions (or enhancements!) that you can make for a better approach are much appreciated.

Comment: @AndyThomas Holger's approach seems far better; it addresses the intent directly -- fetch a property, and if its not null, copy it somewhere else.  (It also happens to create less accidental garbage -- unbound instance method refs are effectively constants.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, your task is to adapt the instance of your type to reflect the properties of a type outside your control. (I’m a bit worried about the `// etc` comment.) In that case, we may encapsulate the “transfer this property, if not `null`” as an operation on it’s own:

```
// in MyType

static <T> BiConsumer<TypeOfArg,MyType> transfer(
        Function<TypeOfArg,T> from, BiConsumer<MyType,T> to) {
    return (arg,myself) -> {
        T value = from.apply(arg);
        if(value!=null) to.accept(myself, value);
    };
}
static final BiConsumer<TypeOfArg,MyType> TRANSFER_ALL_PROPERTIES =
    transfer(TypeOfArg::getH, MyType::setH).andThen(
    transfer(TypeOfArg::getV, MyType::setV).andThen(
    transfer(TypeOfArg::getS, MyType::setS)));

void mutatorMethod(TypeOfArg arg) {
    TRANSFER_ALL_PROPERTIES.accept(arg, this);
}
```

I’m quite sure, that this may also cause debates about whether this is better than an ordinary sequence of `get`-`if`-`set` calls like in your first variant, but I think, this has also a lot to do with familiarity.

To me, `transfer(TypeOfArg::getV, MyType::setV)` expresses intention better than `Optional.ofNullable( arg.getV()).ifPresent( this::setV )`, which still reads much like an imperative statement.

For those, who are concerned about temporary objects, the code doesn’t create any.

Comment: It had also occurred to me that a helper method would be more concise and more clear, though I was thinking of a simpler signature/implementation like `<T> void setMaybe( T val, Consumer<? super T> consumer) { if ( null != val ) consumer.accept(val); }`. But I am still interested in whether the `Optional` approach carries any negative impacts. It relies only on the standard library, rather than introducing an additional dependency or redundant code. Good point about familiarity. By the way, I appreciate your earlier comments on the impacts on performance.

Comment: Expressing the setter as `Consumer` requires a capturing method reference of the `this::setX` form. While, as said, the impacts of temporary objects are often overestimated, a non-capturing solution saves you from the discussion with developers who are concerned about it. Not having to discuss about it, raises your efficiency dramatically. The `Optional` approach adds another temporary, lightweight object, so, it’s also not a matter of performance, but rather readability.

Comment: Thank you for your insights into both the VM and people. :)

Comment: Just in case anyone misunderstands the "creates no temporary objects" description as "allocation-free"... this approach does create some objects too -- the lambda returned from `transfer()` captures `to` and` from`, so an allocation is needed for each call to `transfer()`.  But it is far better than the original; each _use_ of the `TRANSFER` chain creates no garbage -- it is the creation of the chain that involves some objects.  (Even if only used once, it also only creates half as many objects as the OPs example.)    Far more importantly, though, it is way closer to the OPs intent.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is always tricky to answer in a generic way. The truth is: the JVM does so many optimizations that it's hard to say how it will behave for *your* application. Even then, the performance over time will probably be different than the performance measured right after a "cold boot". For instance, if your parameters are not null 99% of the time, branch prediction might turn the performance of both variants insignificant.

In the end, if you are really concerned about the performance, measure it on your own application.

All in all, I'd say that it's better to choose the version you are more comfortable in reading and maintaining. In my case, the pre-Java 8 would win, but that's just me :)